# Lex bot not responding to messages sent through Slack's chat.postMessage API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, amazon-lex

I am building a lex bot that responds to messages on slack channel.
The bot is responding perfectly to messages typed by user in that channel but if the message is send using the `chat.postMessage` API, then the lex bot is not giving any response.

I tried the same with azure bot and it worked perfectly. Any suggestions?

This is the api call I am using:

```
request('slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token='+token+'&channel=DBH3EAK1Q&text=hello&as_user=true', 
    function (error, response, body) { 
      console.log(body);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code, otherwise we can only guess at what you have written.

Comment: Please include formatted code in the question, not a comment.